# How to downgrade svn working copy with svn version?

Tags: svn

I have downgrade my svn from version 1.8 to 1.7.9. Now When i type command like:

```
svn info
svn up
```

or any other commands it give an error that:

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
 (format 31)
```

I want use that copy only.How could i resolve this issue.
I do not want to new checkout. Is there any solution for it.

Any idea..

Comment: why do you need to use an older svn version? why do you not want to check out a new working copy?

Comment: @Sneftel i dont have a backup of my svn working copy with latest revision on my server.So is there any idea that i make working copy same one.

Comment: Just check out a new working copy, and copy your changes into it.

Comment: @SINGH: Did this answer you question? If so, you might want to accept bahrep's answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Official Subversion FAQ has a whole section about this**:

[*"I got an error saying "This client is too old to work with working copy '...' ". How can I fix it without upgrading Subversion?"*](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change).

You have two options:

- Upgrade the client to Subversion 1.8. The working copy has been already checked out or upgraded by SVN 1.8 client, so you might already have 1.8 client installed on your system.
- Checkout a new working copy using Subversion 1.7 client and copy changes from the current one that has 1.8 format.